# Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have copied Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) from my friends Macbook and replaced with my Xcode 8.3.2

When I run my app in any simulator say iPhone 8 or iPhone X, I am getting same error:

Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID com.*****.****

[image]

Simulator is showing black screen and not loading iOS 11

Comment: I think the issue is with Simulator, coz when I run only simulator it should show my apple Icon and load iOS and show home screen, but its not, its just showing me black screen.

Comment: Simple solution to this problem is just download XCode 9.0 from this 
[link](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_GM_seed_build_9A235/Xcode_9_GM_seed.xip)
and run xcode after unzipping and simulator issue will be gone

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags to your question. This question has nothing to do with the Swift programming language or a physical iPhone device.

Comment: I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578409/11079607)

Answer (score 6):

Xcode shouldn't really be simply copied off a system where it's already installed onto a new system. The best solution would be to download the Xcode 9 GM from the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/), or the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) when the Xcode 9 update goes live in a few days. However, before then, you could try running `xcode-select --install` to see if the additional required components are installed with that

Comment: Thanks your answer is quite helpful but still there should be some solution to it, Xcode is running fine, it is compiling source code fine, just issue is with simulator.

Comment: That's correct. Xcode requires separate components that are not necessarily in its bundle in `/Applications` for debugging and testing (i.e. running the simulator). Thus, just copy/pasting Xcode out of somewhere that it's already installed will break those things

Comment: I also copied Xcode from another machine and faced this issue. After trying multiple solutions for a whole day, I just re-installed the Xcode and it worked.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem after moving XCODE app to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by deleting item(key and value) which was wrong in Info.plist.
I think you can try to delete items one by one for checking.

Answer (score 0):

That problem could happen if you your "Build" is empty. [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iQgd.png)