# Xcode 9 - Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, bundle-identifier

Upon updating to Xcode 9 and in the "launching" phase of compilation on the simulator I get the error:

> Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID

[image: Screenshot]

Emphasis placed on this issue only occurs trying to launch the simulator, as working with my actual iPhone 6s launches without any issues .

Attempts:

Ensured info.plist "Bundle Identifier" is correct. it is "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)"

Checked to see if typing the bundle identifier manually would work, but it did not.

Project Cleaned

Deleted Derived Data

Xcode relaunched

Computer Restarted

Xcode betas uninstalled

Xcode Uninstalled and Reinstalled

Provisioning Profile Expires in 11 months

Automatically Manage Signing is unchecked then checked again

Paid Developer for 2 years now and have never had this issue before. Searched online for a solution with no luck and notice only a couple others have had this issue with no clear resolution.

What direction should I take to get this issue resolved. I don't see anything wrong with the provisioning files / certificates, but I could be wrong if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: I have yet to find any documentation for this error on developer.apple.com. Anybody with a possible suggestion to try?

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com and include the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose` taken right after the failure happens. You can also try the Xcode 9.1 beta, it is possible this is an issue that was fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem, this solve it

In you Info.plist:

[Bundle_display_name : Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lT22.png)

set to String value not dictionary

[Bundle_display_name : String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BChMc.png)

i hope this help you

Comment: I have set too, but still not work for me. Pleas help

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[image]

These steps helped me to fix this problem. I found this solution in this [article](https://programmingwithswift.com/easily-fix-failed-to-set-plugin-placeholders-in-xcode/)

Comment: This post saved me after a lot of searching online...thank you [Taras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11079607/taras)!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have come across to continue being able to test your application on the simulator is to download the Xcode 10.3.1 simulators and select those to test your app on.

Best of luck to those who come across this bug!

Answer (score 0):

I think i found solution for this. It works for my case. I did two things:

First(i think this is what really helps) :

- in targets -> general-> Display name i set proper "App name" (i got i grayed before like seted placeholder)

  I tried to set ${PRODUCT_NAME} but i got issues with that (but i think you should try this too)

[General Display Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqKuN.png)

- the in proper info.plist. In bundle name set the same proper "App name".

Same here.I tried to set ${PRODUCT_NAME} but i got issues with that (but i think you should try this too)

[Info.plist Bundle Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BkY7.png)

Second(but i'm pretty sure that was a coincidence) :

I have other project that doesn't have this issue and works fine on all ios versions and simulators.

- In this project(that one which works fine) i set Bundle Identifier from project that doesn't works, but like i said im pretty sure that was only a coincidence

Answer (score 0):

Setting Display Name should fix this. Also making sure your identifier doesn't have funny characters (e.g. -)

Targets > General > Display Name

Answer (score -1):

in my case, after upgraded system, it is fixed automatically

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall Xcode.

1. Copy Xcode.xip from download Directory into Application Directory.
2. Install it.
3. Open your project and run.