# Failed to set plugin placeholders for com.xxx after adding share extension in Xcode 9

Tags: swift3, xcode9, share-extension

[While running the code after adding share extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72evE.png)

Comment: I'm running into the same error, have you happened to solve it by yourself in the meantime?

Comment: where you able to resolve it by anymeans?

Comment: Same issue here.... did you found a fix?

Comment: I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578409/11079607)

Answer (score 2):

You must have different bundleIds for your project and extension.

Example:

- App bundleId: com.companyName.appName
- Extension bundleId: com.companyName.appName.extensionName

I got this error when I set one configuration file for my project and notification service.

I changed the notification service configuration file to the correct one and this fixed my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have properly set your bundle identifiers for your Main app target and extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Enable **Copy only when Installing**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning build folder solved the problem to me. In Xcode, while pressing `alt` on keyboard, choose Product from top menu and click on `Clean Build Folder`

Answer (score 0):

Making sure the configuration for Debug and Release mode is similar for both project and extension resolved this issue.[image]